# pandas sort_values with condition

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that I'd like to sort on cols `time` and `b`, where `b` sort is conditional on value of `a`. So if `a` == 1, sort from highest to lowest, and if `a` == -1, sort from lowest to highest. I would normally do something like `df.sort_values(by=['time', 'b'])` but I think it sorts `b` always from lowest to highest.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [0, 3, 2, 2, 1], 'a': [1, -1, 1, 1, -1], 'b': [4, 5, 1, 6, 2]})


  time  a   b
0   0   1   4
1   3   -1  5
2   2   1   1
3   2   1   6
4   1   -1  2
```

desired output

```
  time  a   b
0   0   1   4
1   1   -1  2
2   2   1   6
3   2   1   1
4   3   -1  5
```

Comment: how do you deal the case when for the same `time`, you have both `a==1` and `a==-1`, which one comes first in your sorting?

Comment: right, so I would remove those cases ideally prior to sorting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply a and b and use it as sorting key:

```
df['sort'] = df['a']*df['b']
df.sort_values(by=['time', 'sort'], ascending=[True, False]).drop('sort', axis=1)
```

output:

```
   time  a  b
0     0  1  4
4     1 -1  2
3     2  1  6
2     2  1  1
1     3 -1  5
```

alternative:

```
df['sort'] = (1-df['a'])*df['b']
df.sort_values(by=['time', 'sort']).drop('sort', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass `ascending` after create additional col for sorting

```
out = df.assign(key = df.a*df.b).sort_values(['time','key'],ascending=[True,False]).drop('key',1)
Out[59]: 
   time  a  b
0     0  1  4
4     1 -1  2
3     2  1  6
2     2  1  1
1     3 -1  5
```